# Insert into“Table1” if a condition is met in “Table” 2 SQL

Tags: php, sql, insert, conditional-statements

**I posted a similar question to this which was about deleting, This one is about inserting.**

Hello,

I'm making a little messaging application in PHP using a SQL database but have faced a small problem. I will try explain this as best as possible so here goes...

I have a table called "users" as following:

```
ID | Username | Password | Email 
-------------------------------------------
1  | Account1 | Pass 1   | email1@mail.com
2  | Account2 | Pass 2   | email2@mail.com
```

I then have another called "friends" as following:

```
UserID | FriendID
------------------
   1   |     2
```

So what I need is a query that will insert data into the "friends" table if a condition is met in the "users" table

Example:

```
INSERT INTO 'friends' VALUES('$UserID', '$FriendID') IF (users.Password = $Password WHERE users.ID = $UserID)
```

I hope that was a good enough explanation but I'm finding this difficult to explain.

Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

This'd probably do

```
INSERT INTO friends (userID, friendID)
SELECT $userID, $friendID
FROM users
WHERE (users.password = $password) and (users.id = $userid)
```

If there where clause matches, you'd however many rows inserted as there are matches, and since you're selecting hardcoded values instead of fields, you'd just get those values inserted into the friends table.

Comment: I might add LIMIT 1 to the end of this. Matching against the users table should probably only return one row but I wouldn't make that assumption myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 INSERT INTO friends VALUES('$UserID', '$FriendID') where UserID in (Select ID from Users where users.Password = '$passoword' and users.ID = '$UserID')
```

Comment: whats the error? can you show the lines of code where you're querying?

Comment: It doesn't work on PostgreSQL with the Error: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

Comment: INSERT does not accept the WHERE keyword, this code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the conditional logic within your application, and not within the SQL. Your application code itself should be responsible for determining whether or not the INSERT should be executed.

Comment: Perhaps suggest then how to use database transactions.  This does not answer the question or do anything to address race conditions common when trying to move this type of logic into the application's code.